# Conjugating multiple verbs in a sentence

Tags: grammaire, verbes, temps-grammatical, participe-présent

I wanted to know how one would conjugate multiple verbs in a single sentence.

For example:

> Michael sat at the table, thinking about what he did.
>
> There was a man at the table, eating quietly.
>
> I heard him yelling and trying to enter the house.
>
> As he ran, feeling the air in his lungs, a man waved in his direction.
>
> Usually I eat, sleep and have a shower before going to work.

What's confusing me the most regarding the first 4 examples is how the present progressive would be rendered in these as the subject is mentioned only at the start of the sentence.

In relation to the fifth example, I thought maybe one could repeat the subject (I/je) for each action.

Overall, I'm wondering what the grammatical rules are regarding multiple verb conjugations in French.

Answer (score 3):

Dans l'ensemble, on trouve des constructions similaires dans les deux langues.

1. Michel était assis à table, pensant à ce qu'il avait fait.
2. Il y avait un homme à la table, mangeant tranquillement.
3. - Je l'ai entendu hurler et essayer d'entrer dans la maison.
   - Je l'ai entendu hurler, essayant d'entrer dans la maison.
   - Je l'ai entendu hurler tout en essayant d'entrer dans la maison.
4. Alors qu'il courait, sentant l'air dans ses poumons, un homme lui fit signe de la main.
5. D'habitude, je fais mon repas, puis je dors avant d'aller au travail.

Dans le dernier cas (5), la solution de répéter le sujet convient et il est difficile de lui trouver un substitut sans répétition du sujet. Cependant pour des action brèves la juxtaposition de formes verbales sans sujet tend à communiquer une certaine idée comme la rapidité du mouvement, la hâte,…, l'âpreté, la langueur,etc.

- Il ouvre la porte, la cogne de sa tête, la claque, commence à lui assener des coups comme un dément, de la bave au coin des lèvres. (frénésie)
- Il arrive, enfile sa tenue, happe un sandwich, puis monte dans sa voiture, et il est partit. (hâte)
- Il fallait absolument que nous y arrivions, forcer le pas, souffrir, ne voir que le but de l'autre côté du col. (âpreté)
- Elle allait de ci de là, flânant, rêvant, prenant du bon temps. (langueur)

Answer (score 2):

Il est plusieurs façons de répondre à ta question. Parmi elles : l'infinitif et le participe présent qui règlent la question de la conjugaison puisque ni l'un ni l'autre ne se conjuguent. Ainsi, je dirais :

1/ Michel s'assit à table **pensant** à ce qu'il avait fait

2/ Il y avait un homme à la table **mangeant** tranquillement

3.1/ Je l'ai entendu **gueuler** et **essayer** d'entrer dans la maison

3.2/ Je l'ai entendu **gueulant** et **essayant** d'entrer dans la maison

4/ Alors qu'il courait, **sentant** l'air dans ses...

5/ D'habitude, je... avant d'**aller** au taf.

Nota : BTW, you last question *overall* is far too braod for being answered here.