# Le pronominaux au présent- how to properly structure sentence?

Tags: grammaire

If I wanted to say he knows how to shave his beard, (present tense) which is correct?

> Oui, il sait se rase la barbe.

OR

> Oui, il sait se raser la barbe.

I know we would say il se rase la barbe without the word knows. I'm not sure how to properly from the sentence with the additional information ( he knows how to shave)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conjugating multiple verbs in a sentence](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/conjugating-multiple-verbs-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is correct:

> Il sait se raser la barbe.

The first one doesn't work because *se rase la barbe* is a present and expects a first person subject before.

> *Il se rase la barbe.* as you wrote is correct.
>
> *Pierre se rase la barbe.* is fine too.

The issue is *Il sait* can't be used as a subject, or even if there are very rare cases where it is usable as a subject (e.g. *Il sait est ce qu'elle compris alors*), it can't be the subject of *se raser* anyway.

In English, I guess a close inconsistency would be:

> <s>He knows is shaving his beard</s>.