# Les verbes pronominaux a l'imparfait

Tags: grammaire

Vouloir + se recontrer

> Oui, nous..............avant la classe

How would you properly complete this sentence using les verbes pronominaux a l'imparfait?

> Oui, nous voulons nous recontrions avant la classe?

That doesn't seem right but I'm not sure how to correct

Comment: Looks like homework. Anyway, *nous voulons nous rencontrions* is incorrect. *Nous voulons* is a present, not an *imparfait* and there is also the same issue that you had with the other question, asked a few minutes earlier. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/le-pronominaux-au-pr%c3%a9sent-how-to-properly-structure-sentence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conjugating multiple verbs in a sentence](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/conjugating-multiple-verbs-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase correcte est:

> Oui, nous voulions nous rencontrer avant la classe.

```
Sujet: Nous
Verbe: Vouloir (voulions car c'est à l'imparfait)
COD, l'action: Se rencontrer (nous rencontrer, car vous êtes plusieurs)
```